# Django createview custom validation

Tags: django, django-validation

I am using createview for creating few fields of a model. I want to provide custom validation to attributes in my form. I am not sure how to do it through the CreateView. I don't want to create a Modelform for it.

Generally custom validation for the attributes is performed by `clean_attr()` method in forms. So, Is there any way to perform this in createview ?

my createview class

```
@method_decorator(never_cache, name='dispatch')
class AppCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = models.App
    fields = ['name', 'background', 'font', 'textcolor']

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(AppCreateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['view'] = 'create'
        return context
```

In the fields, I am excluding a fild called "date" (which has to be today). Is there any way to set the date attribute in CreateView ?

Thanks

**update**

My questions

1. How to make custom validation in AppCreateView ?
2. How to fill the other attributes apart of the user filled ones such as date ?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing; adding the date after submission is not the same as custom validation. Which do you want to do?

Comment: Actually', There are two questions in it. First one is "how to add custom validation in AppCreateView ? ", the second one is "if I have some other parameters such as date (which I want to set in CreateView) how to perform it ?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you can add `validators` on your model which will be catched by `CreateView` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/

For the date, juste add on your field :

```
my_field = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) #the date will be timezone.now() when you save the instance.
```